# How to remove stuff from sink

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, sink, removal, paint-removal

So when I bought my house the bathtubs and sinks were both reglazed (for some reason). I am not sure what it was "reglazed" with, I am just using that term for simplicity. I had the bathtub redone because it was awful. I am replacing the sinks, but the glaze is also on the counter tops. They are the original "wood", I think, from when the house was built in 1993. I really don't want to replace them yet, because the size is an atypical size and I don't have the money to get them rebuilt. How can I remove the glaze from the counter without damaging the countertops? When I replace the sink, the edges will still show. Thanks!

Comment: pics will help us understand, however it is not likely that a glaze can be removed without totally damaging the counter.  Consider butcherblock counters.  The wood can be cut to any size and is cheaper than other solid counters such as granite or quartz.

Comment: It depends on what "wood" means.  Real wood can probably be sanded and refinished.  Most common wood counter tops are probably very thin "wood like" and removing glaze will not be nice.  Paint or recovering might work.

Comment: Confused...you want the remove the "Glaze" then what ?

Comment: @Traveler  Think paint spills on hardwood(hopefully) or laminate wood floors.  Glaze is from repairing sink/tub, not refinishing the top.